# assiging values and compare at the same line how does it work?

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop, conditional-statements

The condition of while loop in the below function

```
void strcpy(char *s, char *t)
    {
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while ((s[i] = t[i]) != '\0')
    i++;
    }
```

the condition here `(s[i] = t[i]) != '\0'` will produce either `0` or `1` 
does it compare the assigning statement to null character?
or 
the value of the i'th element of the 2 arrays to null character?

Answer (score 2):

The assignment expression has a value, which is the left operand after the assignment.

In this example, the condition is testing `s[i] != '\0'` (after executing `s[i] = t[i]`).

Answer (score 1):

It works based on operator precedence.
Highest to lowest:

1. `( )`
2. `!=`
3. `=`

So in your example code, because of the parentheses, assignment happens first then the comparison with '\0'.